# Uploading hashed emails to a server

Tags: java, rest, encoding, hash

I'm trying to understand what the common practice is for signing up new users to a service. They need an email address so that they can log in and be identified later. So, right now I'm using [Google+ sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) to initially log in, but I also need a way to identify each user on our server, so I'm just creating a `MD5` hash of their verified address, then encoding that using `base64` and uploading that to sign them up. Is there a more widely accepted solution to this or is this something that's at least not frowned upon? The whole point was just avoid uploading their address in plain text, so I suppose this is alright?

Answer (score 1):

Albeit unlikely, hashes can collide, so you may later have troubles in identifying your users.

Passwords are stored hashed (to not disclose them even if the attacker gets the authentication database) and salted (to avoid offline dictionary attacks on the stolen database), but I see no point in avoiding to transmit the user email in plain text to your service, because the email address is the public identifier of your user, ie a public piece of data, not something to be kept secret.